# Issue with sony vegas rendering small parts of video

Tags: video, sony

I am trying to render a video in Sony Vegas Pro 13.0 and I have something strange going on. Please see the attached screenshot:

[image]

That section of the video is rendered as full black screen. It should contain 0.5 seconds video cuts, followed by black screens in order to obtain a clipping effect but Sony Vegas will render it as black screen without taking into consideration the small cuts.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your timeline correctly, your video pieces are way shorter than 0.5sec. I would guess, they approx 1/60 sec long. So depending on the rendered framerate and exact the position of the pieces, the image may stay dark. I would suggest you extend your video pieces to the desired length of 0.5sec, that should solve the issue.